# Pull text with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

thank you for stopping by. I am having trouble pulling the usersessionid from this. i am using python seleium. i welcome every asnwer.
Here is the url to the page.

http://www.barneys.com/product/etq-amsterdam--22low-3-22-leather--26-jacquard-sneakers-504720152.html

```
`<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">

        var apiKey= "dbeab3c977a08905",
            clientApiKey = "8ed86f73d8296e2c",
            environment="recs",
            userSessionID= "N5pPRdoSPKl1D7LjwRyqiemXrMy6JWbn65PjU7XsMgQC68XuZsCl!778638265!763427-prodapp2!20580!-1!1474503760402",
            userID= "73558799",
            rrDown = false,
            rrFlag = true;

        var richRelevance = {

            init: function(){
                try{
                    if(typeof r3_common === 'function'){
                        window.R3_COMMON = new r3_common();
```

Comment: You look to be spamming language tags -- why? Please edit your question and use only relevant tags.

Comment: well the code i put up had javascript, and im using python selenium to try to pull

Comment: What does it have to do with Java? You also tagged this language. Understand that tags can increase attention to your question, but mistagging can increase negative attention.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it would be okay to have it extracted using regular expressions:

```
import re

from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.barneys.com/product/etq-amsterdam--22low-3-22-leather--26-jacquard-sneakers-504720152.html")

print(re.search(r'userSessionID\s*=\s*"(.*?)",', driver.page_source).group(1))
```

Prints `p2tPvuezfq3hjHKxe8kIA5JU7b0wRt4dy8Y-L7Bm8PvKv17DiH8X!-603204638!763426-prodapp1!20680!-1!1474511693747`.

Comment: about to try. thank you for your answer

Comment: WORKED PERFECT!! THANK YOU SO MUCH